# Cross communication between two web applications using web requests: is this close to viable?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using the following code to try and learn how pages post, listen and respond between one another using web requests. I begin the process by issuing a request in the first of the two procedures, intending to have the second process retrieve the request and respond back to the calling process. My calling process is receiving a blank response.

Question: Why, and how close to viable is this test?

Here's my two page load events, located in two separate web applications.
Both apps are hosted on IIS:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim sPostURL As String = "http://localhost/DDI_TXListener_Test/Listener_Page.aspx"
    Dim dataToPost As String = String.Empty ' //This is the data for form posting
    Dim HttpWebResponse As System.Net.WebResponse = Nothing
    Dim StreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = Nothing
    Dim respString As String = String.Empty
    Dim stOut As System.IO.Stream = Nothing

    dataToPost = "Name"

    Try
        Dim httpReq As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(sPostURL)

        httpReq.Method = "POST"
        httpReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        Dim byte1 As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToPost)
        httpReq.ContentLength = byte1.Length
        httpReq.Timeout = 10000

        stOut = httpReq.GetRequestStream()
        stOut.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length)
        stOut.Dispose()
        stOut = Nothing

        HttpWebResponse = httpReq.GetResponse()

        StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"))
        respString = StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        If Not StreamReader Is Nothing Then
            StreamReader.Dispose()
            StreamReader = Nothing
        End If
        If Not HttpWebResponse Is Nothing Then
            HttpWebResponse.Close()
            HttpWebResponse = Nothing
        End If
    End Try
    ' <asp:label> control on the html form in front of this code page
    returnedhit.Text = respString
End Sub
```

And I have this as what I hope to use as the receiving/fulfilling end of the above request at:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim sPostURL As String = "http://localhost/DDI_TXRequester_Test/RequesterPage.aspx"
    Dim dataToPost As String = String.Empty ' //This is the data for form posting
    Dim HttpWebResponse As System.Net.WebResponse = Nothing
    Dim StreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = Nothing
    Dim respString As String = String.Empty
    Dim stOut As System.IO.Stream = Nothing

    Try
        Dim httpReq As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(sPostURL)

        HttpWebResponse = httpReq.GetResponse()
        StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"))
        respString = StreamReader.ReadToEnd()


        If respString <> "" Then
            Dim cnt As Integer = 0
            Dim delim As Char() = {"&"c}
            Dim bodpos As Integer = InStr(respString, "<body>") + 6
            Dim respstr As String = Right$(respString, (Len(respString) - bodpos))
            Dim strArr As String() = respstr.Split(delim)
            For Each s As String In strArr
                cnt += 1
                Select Case cnt
                    Case 1
                        Session.Add("opRequested", Right$(Trim(s), (Len(Trim(s)) - 18)))
                    Case Else   '
                End Select
            Next s

            If CStr(Session("opRequested")) = "Name" Then dataToPost = "Name=Jones" Else dataToPost = "Error=Unknown Request"


            httpReq.Method = "POST"
            httpReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            Dim byte1 As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToPost)
            httpReq.ContentLength = byte1.Length
            httpReq.Timeout = 10000

            stOut = httpReq.GetRequestStream()
            stOut.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length)
            stOut.Dispose()
            stOut = Nothing
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        If Not stOut Is Nothing Then
            stOut.Dispose()
            stOut = Nothing
        End If
        If Not StreamReader Is Nothing Then
            StreamReader.Dispose()
            StreamReader = Nothing
        End If
        If Not HttpWebResponse Is Nothing Then
            HttpWebResponse.Close()
            HttpWebResponse = Nothing
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't answer directly but if you are only curious about the data being sent then you could install an application like fiddler

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in that direction. For purposes of clarification of the above, my intention is to have the first procedure issue a webrequest to the second procedure, and to have that request appear to the second procedure as the http response from its perspective. The sPostUrl variable in both procedures is intended to indicate which page is to be the object of the request and response in each case depending on which is the requesting procedure at any given point in time. In every case, it's my intention that the first procedure begins a transaction.

Comment: In other words I'm hopeful of having the page load event of the second procedure triggered by the post action in the first procedure, and when the request arrives as the http response of the second procedure, at that point have the second procedure look at what arrived there in order to determine whether to post back the name or error code. This would then arrive back as the http response of the first procedure.

Comment: What I'm unsure of, having never seen any back end code that would typically process a request such as in the first procedureabove, whether my guess as to backside processing (2nd procedure above) is a viable way to field a request and respond to it.

Comment: Any thoughts or ideas? This is for a business application and for our purposes it's necessary to understand both sides of this.